# How to change the width of this Image Gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, css

I'm trying to add [this gallery](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-1.html) to [my blogger blog](http://indiananimations.blogspot.com/p/page-6.html) and I'm not sure how to change the width. I'm using the following code. My blog's width is 980px. I tried to change 550 into a smaller size, but the images went below!

```
    <style type="text/css">
div.ccontent {
 /* The display of ccontent is enabled using jQuery so that the slideshow ccontent won't display unless javascript is enabled. */
 display: none;
 float: right;
 width: 550px; 
}
div.ccontent a, div.navigation a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #777;
}
div.ccontent a:focus, div.ccontent a:hover, div.ccontent a:active {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
div.controls {
 margin-top: 5px;
 height: 23px;
}
div.controls a {
 padding: 5px;
}
div.ss-controls {
 float: left;
}
div.nav-controls {
 float: right;
}
div.slideshow-container {
 position: relative;
 clear: both;
 height: 502px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
}
div.loader {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-image: url('http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6035/loader.gif');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 width: 550px;
 height: 502px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
}
div.slideshow {

}
div.slideshow span.image-wrapper {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
div.slideshow a.advance-link {
 display: block;
 width: 550px;
 height: 502px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
 line-height: 502px; /* This should be set to be at least the height of the largest image in the slideshow */
 text-align: center;
}
div.slideshow a.advance-link:hover, div.slideshow a.advance-link:active, div.slideshow a.advance-link:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}
div.slideshow img {
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.download {
 float: right;
}
div.caption-container {

}
span.image-caption {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
div.caption {
 background-color: #000;
 padding: 12px;
 color: #ccc;
}
div.caption a {
 color: #fff;
}
div.image-title {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

div.image-desc {
 line-height: 1.3em;
 padding-top: 12px;
}
div.navigation {
 /* The navigation style is set using jQuery so that the javascript specific styles won't be applied unless javascript is enabled. */
}
ul.thumbs {
 clear: both;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul.thumbs li {
 float: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
}
a.thumb {
 padding: 0;
 display: inline;
 border: none;
}
ul.thumbs li.selected a.thumb {
 color: #000;
 font-weight: bold;
}
a.thumb:focus {
 outline: none;
}
ul.thumbs img {
 border: none;
 display: block;
}
div.pagination {
 clear: both;
}
div.navigation div.top {
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 height: 11px;
}
div.navigation div.bottom {
 margin-top: 12px;
}
div.pagination a, div.pagination span.current, div.pagination span.ellipsis {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 2px;
 padding: 4px 7px 2px 7px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
div.pagination a:hover {
 background-color: #eee;
 text-decoration: none;
}
div.pagination span.current {
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #000;
 border-color: #000;
 color: #fff;
}
div.pagination span.ellipsis {
 border: none;
 padding: 5px 0 3px 2px;
}
#captionToggle a {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 background-image: url('http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2515/captionj.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: right;
 margin-top: 5px;
 padding: 5px 30px 5px 5px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://galleriffic.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/example/js/jquery.galleriffic.js"></script>

<div id="page">
   <div id="container">
    <h1><a href="index.html">Galleriffic</a></h1>
    <h2>Minimal implementation</h2>

    <!-- Start Minimal Gallery Html Containers -->
    <div id="gallery" class="ccontent">
     <div id="controls" class="controls"></div>
     <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div id="loading" class="loader"></div>
      <div id="slideshow" class="slideshow"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
     <ul class="thumbs noscript">
      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3261/2538183196_8baf9a8015.jpg" title="Title #0">Title #0</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2404/2538171134_2f77bc00d9.jpg" title="Title #1">Title #1</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2093/2538168854_f75e408156.jpg" title="Title #2">Title #2</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3153/2538167690_c812461b7b.jpg" title="Title #3">Title #3</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3150/2538167224_0a6075dd18.jpg" title="Title #4">Title #4</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3204/2537348699_bfd38bd9fd.jpg" title="Title #5">Title #5</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3124/2538164582_b9d18f9d1b.jpg" title="Title #6">Title #6</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3205/2538164270_4369bbdd23.jpg" title="Title #7">Title #7</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3211/2538163540_c2026243d2.jpg" title="Title #8">Title #8</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2315/2537343449_f933be8036.jpg" title="Title #9">Title #9</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2167/2082738157_436d1eb280.jpg" title="Title #10">Title #10</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2342/2083508720_fa906f685e.jpg" title="Title #11">Title #11</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2132/2082721339_4b06f6abba.jpg" title="Title #12">Title #12</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2139/2083503622_5b17f16a60.jpg" title="Title #13">Title #13</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2041/2083498578_114e117aab.jpg" title="Title #14">Title #14</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2149/2082705341_afcdda0663.jpg" title="Title #15">Title #15</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2014/2083478274_26775114dc.jpg" title="Title #16">Title #16</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2194/2083464534_122e849241.jpg" title="Title #17">Title #17</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3127/2538173236_b704e7622e.jpg" title="Title #18">Title #18</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2375/2538172432_3343a47341.jpg" title="Title #19">Title #19</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2353/2083476642_d00372b96f.jpg" title="Title #20">Title #20</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2201/1502907190_7b4a2a0e34.jpg" title="Title #21">Title #21</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1116/1380178473_fc640e097a.jpg" title="Title #22">Title #22</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a class="thumb" href="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1260/930424599_e75865c0d6.jpg" title="Title #23">Title #23</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End Minimal Gallery Html Containers -->
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">&copy; 2009 Trent Foley</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   // We only want these styles applied when javascript is enabled
   $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '300px', 'float' : 'left'});
   $('div.ccontent').css('display', 'block');

   $(document).ready(function() {    
    // Initialize Minimal Galleriffic Gallery
    $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
     imageContainerSel:      '#slideshow',
     controlsContainerSel:   '#controls'
    });
   });
  </script>
```

Comment: change in CSS what ever width you need.As clearly from your blog I could find that bot the css(i.e the gallerific CSS and your main blog CSS) are conflicting so the contents moved to right So you need to see what are the conflictions in both and make changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need any scripting for this. `div.slideshow-container{margin-left:-25px}` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("thumbs").style.width = "123px";
```

Comment: In a JavaScript file and then request the file with script tags at the bottom of your HTML body content.

Comment: Will this work? `<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("thumbs").style.width = "123px";
</script>`

Comment: It will, but I still recommend moving that code to an external JavaScript file and instead using <script src="pathtoyourfile"></script> in your HTML.